# Rails server not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following Hartl's Rails Tutorial and everything was going well until I tried to run the rails server command, (Section 1.3.2). At which point it [wigged the heck out](http://drawchange.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Capture.jpg) and hours of rabbit trails on the web later have gotten me nothing. I've checked the gems and all dependencies are satisfied. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any error codes being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an old beta version of the web_console gem. Upgrade it to the latest version which removed the PTY stuff. To upgrade it, make sure that the entry for web_console in your Gemfile specifies no version. The entry in Gemfile should look like:

```
gem 'web_console'
```

Then from the command line run:

```
bundle update web_console
```

Comment: Ok getting closer! Now it has this error. http://drawchange.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Capture1.jpg